# MVC 5 does not contain a definition for bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a drop down on the nav bar for this MVC project and getting a "does not contain a definition for bootstrap error." Sorry if this question is stupid but this is my first time creating a website using ASP and MVC.

Whenever I run it I get an Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpCompileExpection' occured in System.Web.dll but was not handled in uesr code.

Here is my _LoginPartial view

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @using (var dd = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new DropDown("Manage")))
            {
                @dd.ActionLink("Account", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
                @dd.Action("Posts", "Manage", "Book", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
            }
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
}
}
else
{
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
</ul>
}
```

Here is the head of my _layout.cshtml

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - Books4CSUSM</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
```

Here is the body of my _layout.cshtml

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Books4CSUSM", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Books", "Index", "Book")</li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Books4CSUSM</p>
    </footer>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I did not install TwitterBootstrapMVC with nuget. I installed TwitterBootstrap 3 and just used the regular syntax for html.

```
<li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Manage <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Manage Account", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })</li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Manage Posts", "Manage", "Book", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the included code, I assume this reference `Html.Bootstrap()` is the issue.  Bootstrap() is defined as an extension method of HtmlHelper, but MVC can't find it, hence this exception.  Add a using statement to add the namespace where the bootstrap framework is defined.

Comment: I have tried this and have had no luck. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: What namespace is it defined in?  There wasn't any using in your code sample?  Also, is this Twitter Bootstrap MVC?  OR something else?